# How to solve an Oracle error if it writes that "file not found"?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

my native language is not English, so I hope you will understand my problem. I go to a driving school, I found on the Internet the full version of the disk with tests that I need to solve in order to pass the exam well in the end, the program is not free, but I found a free version. I downloaded the program to my computer, found a tutorial video on how to install the program. Up to some point, everything was fine, but the Oracle program gave this error. Tell me what to do and how to fix it? I will be soo grateful

Error Message: `Error opening 'C:\Users\a\Downloads\PDD_2021-disk001.vmdk' for reading (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).`

Error code: `VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)`

Component: `ApplianceWrap`

Interface:  `IAppliance {86a98347-7619-41aa-aece-b21ac5c1a7e6}`

Comment: That's not exactly for Stack Overflow; error message indicates you're having problems with Oracle VirtualBox. I suggest you visit their forum (here's one discussion about VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=94872) and see what they say about it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is simple - Oracle Virtual Box references a disk image (vmdk) that isn't in the archive/missing.
You need to find it ant put it in C:\Users\a\Downloads\ for it to work...

R